# Snap SPARQL Query: Classes

Tags: sparql, protege

I have a question regarding the "snap SPARQL query" in Protege.
I have the following ontology:

```
@prefix : myOntology#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <myOntology> .

<myOntology> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  myOntology#hasCalories
:hasCalories rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
             rdfs:range :Calories .


###  myOntology#hasTaste
:hasTaste rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:range :Taste .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  myOntology#BakeryProduct
:BakeryProduct rdf:type owl:Class ;
               rdfs:subClassOf :Food ;
               owl:disjointWith :Sweets .


###  myOntology#Bread
:Bread rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf :BakeryProduct ,
                       [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                         owl:hasValue :lowCalories
                       ] .


###  myOntology#Bun
:Bun rdf:type owl:Class ;
     rdfs:subClassOf :BakeryProduct ,
                     [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                       owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                       owl:hasValue :mediumCalories
                     ] .


###  myOntology#Cake
:Cake rdf:type owl:Class ;
      rdfs:subClassOf :BakeryProduct ,
                      [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                        owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                        owl:hasValue :highCalories
                      ] ,
                      [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                        owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                        owl:hasValue :sweetTaste
                      ] .


###  myOntology#Calories
:Calories rdf:type owl:Class ;
          owl:disjointWith :Food .


###  myOntology#Chocolate
:Chocolate rdf:type owl:Class ;
           rdfs:subClassOf :Sweets ,
                           [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                             owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                             owl:hasValue :highCalories
                           ] ,
                           [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                             owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                             owl:hasValue :sweetTaste
                           ] .


###  myOntology#FastFood
:FastFood rdf:type owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf :Food .


###  myOntology#Food
:Food rdf:type owl:Class .


###  myOntology#GummiBears
:GummiBears rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf :Sweets ,
                            [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                              owl:unionOf ( [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                              owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                                              owl:hasValue :saltyTaste
                                            ]
                                            [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                              owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                                              owl:hasValue :sweetTaste
                                            ]
                                          )
                            ] ,
                            [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                              owl:hasValue :mediumCalories
                            ] .


###  myOntology#HeartyTaste
:HeartyTaste rdf:type owl:Class ;
             rdfs:subClassOf :Taste .


###  myOntology#HighCalorieProduct
:HighCalorieProduct rdf:type owl:Class ;
                    owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                          owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                                          owl:hasValue :highCalories
                                        ] ;
                    rdfs:subClassOf :Products ;
                    owl:disjointWith :LowCalorieProduct .


###  myOntology#HighCalories
:HighCalories rdf:type owl:Class ;
              rdfs:subClassOf :Calories .


###  myOntology#HotDog
:HotDog rdf:type owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf :FastFood ,
                        [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                          owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                          owl:hasValue :highCalories
                        ] ,
                        [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                          owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                          owl:hasValue :heartyTaste
                        ] ,
                        [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                          owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                          owl:hasValue :saltyTaste
                        ] ;
        owl:disjointWith :Pizza .


###  myOntology#LowCalorieProduct
:LowCalorieProduct rdf:type owl:Class ;
                   owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                         owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                                         owl:hasValue :lowCalories
                                       ] ;
                   rdfs:subClassOf :Products .


###  myOntology#LowCalories
:LowCalories rdf:type owl:Class ;
             rdfs:subClassOf :Calories .


###  myOntology#MediumCalories
:MediumCalories rdf:type owl:Class ;
                rdfs:subClassOf :Calories .


###  myOntology#Pizza
:Pizza rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf :FastFood ,
                       [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty :hasCalories ;
                         owl:hasValue :highCalories
                       ] ,
                       [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                         owl:hasValue :heartyTaste
                       ] ,
                       [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty :hasTaste ;
                         owl:hasValue :saltyTaste
                       ] .


###  myOntology#Products
:Products rdf:type owl:Class .


###  myOntology#SaltyTaste
:SaltyTaste rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf :Taste .


###  myOntology#SweetTaste
:SweetTaste rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf :Taste .


###  myOntology#Sweets
:Sweets rdf:type owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf :Food .


###  myOntology#Taste
:Taste rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  myOntology#heartyTaste
:heartyTaste rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                      :HeartyTaste .


###  myOntology#highCalories
:highCalories rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                       :HighCalories .


###  myOntology#lowCalories
:lowCalories rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                      :LowCalories .


###  myOntology#mediumCalories
:mediumCalories rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                         :MediumCalories .


###  myOntology#saltyTaste
:saltyTaste rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                     :SaltyTaste .


###  myOntology#sweetTaste
:sweetTaste rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                     :SweetTaste .


#################################################################
#    General axioms
#################################################################

[ rdf:type owl:AllDisjointClasses ;
  owl:members ( :BakeryProduct
                :FastFood
                :Sweets
              )
] .


[ rdf:type owl:AllDisjointClasses ;
  owl:members ( :Calories
                :Products
                :Taste
              )
] .


[ rdf:type owl:AllDisjointClasses ;
  owl:members ( :HeartyTaste
                :SaltyTaste
                :SweetTaste
              )
] .


[ rdf:type owl:AllDisjointClasses ;
  owl:members ( :HighCalories
                :LowCalories
                :MediumCalories
              )
] .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Now, through the reasoner, the classes with the relation "hasCalories value highCalories" have been defined as a subclass of the class "HighCalorieProduct".

Now through the snap SPARQL query I want to find the classes with many calories that have a sweet taste. Not the instances!

With a SPARQL query I would formulate the query like this:

```
PREFIX te: <myOntology#>
SELECT ?food
WHERE { 
    ?food rdfs:subClassOf te:HighCalorieProduct;
        rdfs:subClassOf ?taste.

    ?taste owl:onProperty te:hasTaste;
        owl:hasValue te:sweetTaste.
 }
```

However, in Snap SPARQL I cannot use the expression "**owl:onProperty**".

How can I search in Snap SPARQL for the classes with many calories and a sweet taste?

Thank you!